# When/where was <FH> used for /f/?

Tags: orthography, spelling, inscription, old-latin

It's generally accepted that the oldest Latin inscription is on the Praenestine Fibula:

> MANIOS MED FHE FHAKED NUMASIOI

The verb here seems to be an old reduplicated perfect of *faciō*, equivalent to Classical *fēcit*.

I know I've seen this spelling, <FH> for `/f/`, before—but I can't seem to remember or find the context. So: when and where was this spelling used? Was it common in very early Latin, or in another nearby language? And when did it die out?

Comment: Was P already in use at that time? My immediate thought is that FH could stand for PH.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta I would think so (that `P` was already in use), because we see both the voiced `D` and the unvoiced `K` used in the expected places here—though I'm not sure.

Comment: FH was sometimes used in Etruscan for [f], but AFAIK isn't found elsewhere in Latin.

Comment: @TKR Oh, that might be what I'm thinking of! But didn't Etruscan innovate a new glyph for `/f/`, looking roughly like a number 8?

Comment: Yes, both were used: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etruscan_alphabet#Development

Comment: @TKR That would be what I'm thinking of then! Feel free to post that as an answer, since that's most likely where the inscriber of the Fibula got the convention from.

Comment: F has its origin in the digamma, which generally had value /w/: I have always supposed that FH was being used for a sort of "breathed" (devoiced) /w/: in principle /ʍ/, but readily generalised to /ɸ/ (as in Maori) and to /f/.

Comment: @ColinFine That would make a lot of sense, especially since we see the same use of H for voiceless /r/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The digraph FH was used in early Etruscan inscriptions to represent [f], though it was later replaced by a new sign, looking like the number . ([Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etruscan_alphabet#Development) has some more information on this.)

As far as I know, FH is not known to have been used in Latin anywhere other than in the Praeneste fibula. Its use for [f] on the fibula (which has sometimes been thought to be a forgery) is actually a strong argument for its authenticity, since at the time the fibula came to light, the value of Etruscan FH as [f] was not yet known.

Comment: Addendum: In (sinistroverse) Etruscan inscriptions, we can see the digraph , which is *usually* transliterated as **vh** - see virtually everything written by the greatest Etruscologists Rix or Wallace (cf. Weiss <wh>).